# "To X, to Y," vs "to X, to Y"

Tags: punctuation

In the novel Me Before You. I stumbled into this sentence:

> But to actively, to voluntarily, play a part in her own son's death?

I was surprised because [Google Books](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=IYH&biw=839&bih=954&tbm=bks&ei=Q16CXKbKEYTI8wW5rrrAAQ&q=%22to+actively%2C+to+voluntarily%22&oq=%22to+actively%2C+to+voluntarily%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...126573.128952.0.129136.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.aNIYJYF-NKY) also has a version without the last comma:

Does this mean the comma is optional in cases like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An awful lot of commas are stylistic. In this case, I would generally prefer not to use the comma; it creates the impression that *voluntarily* is part of a parenthetical, and it shouldn't be - it's too fundamental to the whole.

Stylistically, I also wouldn't repeat *to*. Those are two adverbs for the same verb, so you don't need to repeat *to*.